# Attaching External HD to Airport - Is It Secure?

Tags: hard-drive, security, airport, external-disk

I am thinking about attaching an external HD to my Airpot (ac), which I will use to back up my computer using SuperDuper on a nightly basis. However, I am concerned about security. I know that I can set a password to access the disk. But is the disk available via the internet? I'm concerned that someone outside my network might be able to access the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Disks connected to an Airport router aren't, by default, accessible from the Internet. This is for a few reasons:

1. Your ISP is almost certainly running firewalls that would make it hard to do this anyway.
2. By default, disks are only accessible from your local network.

That said, it's *possible* to make a disk accessible from the Internet if you want to - see [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3413) on the Apple support forums. If you don't specifically take those steps, the disk won't be publicly accessible.